# VHost is showing only "it works" instead of project pages

Tags: apache, http, httpd.conf, vhosts

I've developed virtual hosts in my mac but instead of showing the project its showing "it works".
I have a java application, this is my **httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/lalarukh/data/code/prestige-apis"
    ServerName labraize.in

    <Directory "/Users/lalarukh/data/code/prestige-apis">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**etc/hosts** file:
`127.0.0.1 labraize.in`

Uncommented the required lines also in **httpd.conf** file.
For testing purpose I made a directory in my server folder named **test**. And made **index.html** file inside. And called it in hosts as **http://test.com** But it also returned "It works".

Means that apache vhosts can't get inside the code directory that's why its not working.

vhosts showing 'it works' instead of project pages.

Answer (score 0):

The vhost is listening on port `8080` and not the default `80` so if you want to reach the correct vhost, you need to add `:8080` at the end of the URL so in theory: http://labraize.in:8080 should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm already using 8080 port to call out. When I use 80 it gives forbidden error. That's why I know apache server is running on 8080 port. And because of this its showing "It works" output.